# Unwanted space being taken up by Textview for Html.fromhtml

Tags: android, html, android-layout

**Case 1**

**Below is the code that I have used to set text as Html inside the textview but it is taking up the space for the link that is present. Though the same is not visible.**

```
holder.textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDataset.get(position).getHomeScreenData().getNews().getNdata()));
```

[image: Check the extra blank space here.]

**Case 2**

**Below is the code that I have used to set plain text in the textview and as expected it is taking the required space.**

```
holder.textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.textView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getHomeScreenData().getNews().getNdata());
```

[image]

I want to remove the extra space that is being taken up by the invisible link . How can I do this.

**Edit 1**

My XML declaration for TextView,

```
<TextView
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Here goes the latest NEWS!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this way you can `trim` the `string data` to remove the extra space and fit inside the layout.

```
CharSequence trimmed = trim(Html.fromHtml(mDataset.get(position).getHomeScreenData().getNews().getNdata()));
holder.textView.setText(trimmed);
holder.textView.setClickable(true);
holder.textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: don't use `android:autoLink="web"` attribute with it. because it causes LinkMovementMethod doesn't work.

Comment: @Prateek set `setMovementMethod` below `setText`. and also check after `trim` you get the perfect link or not.

Comment: There are no spaces in the url hence it looks good to me but still it is not working by setting `setMovementMethod` below `setText`

Comment: @Prateek set this `holder.textView.setClickable(true);` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hii you can remove space between textview using follwing code

```
holder.textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.textView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getHomeScreenData().getNews().getNdata().trim());
```

Comment: both line use  it will help you